# AJAX By File://

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I have created an AJAX based app. It's working perfect when I use my Apache server as http://localhost:8081/ but when I try to directly open the .html file in browser by file:// prefix, it fails to other pages by ajax.

```
http://localhost:8081/ works perfect
```

`file:///Users/devbrats/Documents/WimBim/www/index.html#Login.html` it never loads Login.html inside index.html body div

why this is so?

Comment: Please show the full URL of the document you're in, and the URL you are loading.

Comment: Is this not an issue with Same Origin Policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. I always code straight from my server (which is on my development computer), or ftp into it with [Shiftedit](http://shiftedit.net), (which is really awesome)

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers impose slightly different limitations when it comes to running JavaScript on file:/// URLs, but in general they impose higher restrictions than when running from a webserver.  Last I checked, Chrome at least disallows XHR completely in this scenario.

So yes, you're generally better off testing JS-heavy applications from an actual webserver, especially if that's where you intend to be running it eventually anyway.

Comment: Yes. But if my app is going to be inside PhoneGap how can I better do that? My web app has cross domains ajax calls also. How can I efficiently do them all?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests only work on urls from the same host as the webpage it is called from. Local files don't work because it imposes a security risk, because any site could load a local file and send it to the host.

A quick google search gave me this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File (Android & BB only)

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage (Android, BB, iphone)

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/829884c7fe517f56/073a2d2a57fd3a69?lnk=gst&q=ajax#073a2d2a57fd3a69

Comment: isn't this link confusing about what you are saying?